# Cypress test fails but works when tested manually

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to test the ability to retrieve results from a database. When running a test that logs in, navigates to the search tab and searches a word, I am getting a 401. If I go to the website, use the same log in information and do the exact same steps, it works perfectly. Here's the last few steps of the test:

```
cy.contains('Search').click(); //open tab
cy.contains('Search by').click();
cy.contains('Name').click(); 
cy.get('.search-field').type('Jane');
cy.get('.search-btn').click();
```

There's a drop down menu for what you want to search by, a textfield for the search word and a search button. I can't share all of the code but I can see from the video that logging in and all the following steps are performed as supposed to. What kind of things can cause a cypress test to return different results as opposed to manually performing the action? I added `wait(2000)`'s in between the steps but it made no difference.

Comment: There are a few things in your test that can cause different results. First, you do not show any assertions after your actions in your shared steps and one can imagine you do not have many in your tests. We don't know what your app does or how it behaves on the actions. You can share the rest of your steps and scrub any work sensitive text. Second, I see your perform a click that will open a new tab. Are you handling that correct with the cypress limitation of only one tab? There are ways to open the link within the same window.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is an event that needs to be triggered before the page is able to search.

Take a look at the element you are typing into in the devtools, under the Event Listeners tab.

For example, the StackOverflow search box has an event for `s-popover:show` listed there - if testing that you would `.trigger('s-popover:show')` to fire that event and display the instruction tooltip.

So try something like this

```js
cy.get('.search-field')
  .type('Jane')
  .trigger('change')  // or .trigger('input')
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress deletes localStorage in between tests. In this case that deleted the authorization token which is why I was getting the 401. I installed this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands

After the log in I use

```
cy.saveLocalStorage();
```

And before making search

```
cy.restoreLocalStorage();
```